# Problems at the milliners?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Today I've been compiling some C++ code that makes heavy use of Boost Spirit. So lots of time waiting. I've spent the time diving in and out of Stack Overflow.

Hats off to me if I may say so myself: I've hit the reputation cap, answered a handful of questions, and have even had two answers accepted. Might have even picked up the odd downvote on the way too.

But no hats awarded for my efforts?!

What am I to do?

Comment: You _could_ stop in at https://stackoverflow.com/teams and earn the [Team Player](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/team-player) hat...

Comment: well you got one from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actions *should* have awarded you the [Top(bar) Hat](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/topbar-hat) (unless you already earned it yesterday, of course). Otherwise, try doing something which *does* award a hat, e.g.

- get three more accepted answers for [Rep Hunter](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter)
- help a new user and hope your answer gets accepted before it is upvoted for [Explorer](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/explorer)
- make yourself useful in the <s>treadmills</s> review queues to get [Peacekeeper](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/peacekeeper); your fellow Stack Exchange users will thank you for that

Comment: Ah I see. The standards are high this year!